Could not load type 'Sustainsys.Saml2.WebSso.Saml2Module' from assembly 'Sustainsys.Saml2'
"I'm implementing SSO login using SAML authentication with Okta as the Identity Provider (IDP) in a **.NET Framework 4.8.1 **web API application. After setting up the Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) URL, we successfully triggered the ACS method and placed a debug point. To access the user details from the SAML assertion, I need an external library/package, so I'm using 'Sustainsys.Saml2'. According to the official documentation and reference sites, the first step is to add some configuration settings to the web.config file, as shown below."
Refer to the system.webserver tag from web.config attached in the below screenshots.
As soon as this line add name = Saml2Module is added when the application is started
the above error occurs.
Please refer to the below error message
Error message after adding the above config in system.webserver
SAML package installed from nugget manager latest version 2.9.2
Web.config file ](https://i.sstatic.net/AJXPW2X8.png)
Web.config part 2
